# Examples of palindromic polynomial sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, oeis

In the OEIS you can find the coefficients of the h-polynomials for the associahedra, the Narayana polynomials [A001263](https://oeis.org/A001263); for the stellahedra, [A046802](https://oeis.org/A046802); and for the permutahedra, the Eulerian polynomials [A008292](https://oeis.org/A008292). These h-polynomials as bivariate polynomials share the property that they are palindromic, i.e., the coefficients of the first half of the polynomials are the reverse, or a reflection of the second half; e.g., for the Eulerians

$E_4(a,b) = 1a^4 + 26a^3b + 66a^2b^2 + 26ab^3 + 1b^4.$

A second property, call it the $\Omega$ property, is that the absolute values of the coefficients of the first half of each polynomial (except for the linear polynomial) is increasing and therefore the second half, decreasing. (I believe this is true for all the h-polynomials above except for the first degree polynomials.)

I have rarely come across the converse situation, call it the U property, where there is a reflection symmetry but the first half is decreasing in absolute value rather than increasing. In fact, I can vaguely recall exploring such an OEIS entry long ago and have just come across a second example in the numerator polynomials of the power series expansion about $x=0$ of the square root of a quadratic equation; that is,

$$  \sqrt{1-x/z_1} \sqrt{1-x/z_2} = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-x)^{n}\sum_{k= 0 }^n \binom{1/2}{k} \binom{1/2}{n-k}(1/z_1)^k(1/z_2)^{n-k}$$

$= 1 - \frac{z_1 + z_2}{2 z_1 z_2}x - \frac{(z_1 - z_2)^2}{2^3 (z_1 z_2)^2}x^2 - \frac{(z_1 - z_2)^2 (z_1 + z_2)}{2^4 (z_1 z_2)^3}x^3 - \frac{(z_1 - z_2)^2 (5 z_1^2 + 6 z_2 z_1 + 5 z_2^2)}{2^7 (z_1 z_2)^4}x^4 - \frac{(z_1 - z_2)^2 (7 z_1^3 + 9 z_2 z_1^2 + 9 z_2^2 z_1 + 7 z_2^3)}{2^8 (z_1 z_2)^5}x^5 - \frac{(z_1 - z_2)^2 (21 z_1^4 + 28 z_2 z_1^3 + 30 z_2^2 z_1^2 + 28 z_2^3 z_1 + 21 z_2^4}{2^{10} (z_1 z_2)^6}x^6 + O(x^7) $

$= 1 - \frac{(z_1 + z_2)}{2 z_1 z_2)}x - \frac{z_1^2 - 2 z_2 z_1 + z_2^2}{2^3 (z_1 z_2)^2}x^2 - \frac{z_1^3 - z_2 z_1^2 - z_2^2 z_1 + z_2^3}{2^4 (z_1z_2)^3}x^3 - \frac{5 z_1^4 - 4 z_2 z_1^3 - 2 z_2^2 z_1^2 - 4 z_2^3 z_1 + 5 z_2^4}{2^7 (z_1z_2)^4}x^4 - \frac{7 z_1^5 - 5 z_2 z_1^4 - 2 z_2^2 z_1^3 - 2 z_2^3 z_1^2 - 5 z_2^4 z_1 + 7 z_2^5}{2^8 (z_1 z_2)^5}x^5 - \frac{21 z_1^6 - 14 z_2 z_1^5 - 5 z_2^2 z_1^4 - 4 z_2^3 z_1^3 - 5 z_2^4 z_1^2 - 14 z_2^5 z_1 + 21 z_2^6}{2^{10} (z_1 z_2)^6}x^6 + O(x^7).$

I haven't proven it, but I believe the U property holds for all the numerator polynomials of order four and higher. The first and last coefficients of the polynomials, the alleged highest in absolute value, are [A098597](https://oeis.org/A098597) / [A002596](https://oeis.org/A002596), related to the Catalan numbers, and the signed coefficients sum to zero for order 2 and above. With a change of variables these polynomials become essentially the Narayana polynomials.

I think one can write a script to search the OEIS database for examples of U polynomials, but I don't know how to do so. Can anyone provide examples from the OEIS (or elsewhere) of other U polynomial sequences, particularly those which belong to families sharing some combinatorial property, such as the h-polynomials above share?

Comment: Linking [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2940843/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4174786/11619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53895/11619), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4006293/11619). I started searching because this polynomial rang a bell :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/08085c75cfb627c400104a00236f5cd0) that finds all OEIS sequences which, when interpreted as triangular arrays, are palindromic and U-shaped in each row. Most of them aren’t directly related to polynomials, but some specify generating functions (e.g. [A078391](https://oeis.org/A078391), which is related to the Catalan numbers). Here’s the resulting list of links:

[A001231](https://oeis.org/A001231)
[A003984](https://oeis.org/A003984)
[A010032](https://oeis.org/A010032)
[A027420](https://oeis.org/A027420)
[A048147](https://oeis.org/A048147)
[A048149](https://oeis.org/A048149)
[A049581](https://oeis.org/A049581)
[A049723](https://oeis.org/A049723)
[A049735](https://oeis.org/A049735)
[A049747](https://oeis.org/A049747)
[A049751](https://oeis.org/A049751)
[A051125](https://oeis.org/A051125)
[A059366](https://oeis.org/A059366)
[A067804](https://oeis.org/A067804)
[A068555](https://oeis.org/A068555)
[A073254](https://oeis.org/A073254)
[A074911](https://oeis.org/A074911)
[A078391](https://oeis.org/A078391)
[A080382](https://oeis.org/A080382)
[A083457](https://oeis.org/A083457)
[A084867](https://oeis.org/A084867)
[A085484](https://oeis.org/A085484)
[A085517](https://oeis.org/A085517)
[A098361](https://oeis.org/A098361)
[A101037](https://oeis.org/A101037)
[A103451](https://oeis.org/A103451)
[A103516](https://oeis.org/A103516)
[A108063](https://oeis.org/A108063)
[A114929](https://oeis.org/A114929)
[A114972](https://oeis.org/A114972)
[A115253](https://oeis.org/A115253)
[A115255](https://oeis.org/A115255)
[A116588](https://oeis.org/A116588)
[A129821](https://oeis.org/A129821)
[A131816](https://oeis.org/A131816)
[A131821](https://oeis.org/A131821)
[A131843](https://oeis.org/A131843)
[A131844](https://oeis.org/A131844)
[A131919](https://oeis.org/A131919)
[A134634](https://oeis.org/A134634)
[A140685](https://oeis.org/A140685)
[A143180](https://oeis.org/A143180)
[A143182](https://oeis.org/A143182)
[A143183](https://oeis.org/A143183)
[A144155](https://oeis.org/A144155)
[A144216](https://oeis.org/A144216)
[A144217](https://oeis.org/A144217)
[A154869](https://oeis.org/A154869)
[A155169](https://oeis.org/A155169)
[A155720](https://oeis.org/A155720)
[A155725](https://oeis.org/A155725)
[A156003](https://oeis.org/A156003)
[A156047](https://oeis.org/A156047)
[A156130](https://oeis.org/A156130)
[A157050](https://oeis.org/A157050)
[A157927](https://oeis.org/A157927)
[A161419](https://oeis.org/A161419)
[A169894](https://oeis.org/A169894)
[A171824](https://oeis.org/A171824)
[A173049](https://oeis.org/A173049)
[A173424](https://oeis.org/A173424)
[A173476](https://oeis.org/A173476)
[A176081](https://oeis.org/A176081)
[A176862](https://oeis.org/A176862)
[A181262](https://oeis.org/A181262)
[A183632](https://oeis.org/A183632)
[A183642](https://oeis.org/A183642)
[A183652](https://oeis.org/A183652)
[A183662](https://oeis.org/A183662)
[A183672](https://oeis.org/A183672)
[A183680](https://oeis.org/A183680)
[A183918](https://oeis.org/A183918)
[A183986](https://oeis.org/A183986)
[A184003](https://oeis.org/A184003)
[A184029](https://oeis.org/A184029)
[A184039](https://oeis.org/A184039)
[A184048](https://oeis.org/A184048)
[A184386](https://oeis.org/A184386)
[A184457](https://oeis.org/A184457)
[A184477](https://oeis.org/A184477)
[A184505](https://oeis.org/A184505)
[A186609](https://oeis.org/A186609)
[A186619](https://oeis.org/A186619)
[A187645](https://oeis.org/A187645)
[A198063](https://oeis.org/A198063)
[A198064](https://oeis.org/A198064)
[A198065](https://oeis.org/A198065)
[A203994](https://oeis.org/A203994)
[A204004](https://oeis.org/A204004)
[A204008](https://oeis.org/A204008)
[A204022](https://oeis.org/A204022)
[A204123](https://oeis.org/A204123)
[A204143](https://oeis.org/A204143)
[A204154](https://oeis.org/A204154)
[A204156](https://oeis.org/A204156)
[A204158](https://oeis.org/A204158)
[A204237](https://oeis.org/A204237)
[A204284](https://oeis.org/A204284)
[A204361](https://oeis.org/A204361)
[A204370](https://oeis.org/A204370)
[A204381](https://oeis.org/A204381)
[A204408](https://oeis.org/A204408)
[A204417](https://oeis.org/A204417)
[A204492](https://oeis.org/A204492)
[A204501](https://oeis.org/A204501)
[A204607](https://oeis.org/A204607)
[A204754](https://oeis.org/A204754)
[A206772](https://oeis.org/A206772)
[A209727](https://oeis.org/A209727)
[A209898](https://oeis.org/A209898)
[A224651](https://oeis.org/A224651)
[A224658](https://oeis.org/A224658)
[A224806](https://oeis.org/A224806)
[A227074](https://oeis.org/A227074)
[A227075](https://oeis.org/A227075)
[A227076](https://oeis.org/A227076)
[A227550](https://oeis.org/A227550)
[A227581](https://oeis.org/A227581)
[A231205](https://oeis.org/A231205)
[A233997](https://oeis.org/A233997)
[A234140](https://oeis.org/A234140)
[A234227](https://oeis.org/A234227)
[A234266](https://oeis.org/A234266)
[A234490](https://oeis.org/A234490)
[A234549](https://oeis.org/A234549)
[A234564](https://oeis.org/A234564)
[A234658](https://oeis.org/A234658)
[A234665](https://oeis.org/A234665)
[A234672](https://oeis.org/A234672)
[A234681](https://oeis.org/A234681)
[A234690](https://oeis.org/A234690)
[A234702](https://oeis.org/A234702)
[A234712](https://oeis.org/A234712)
[A234728](https://oeis.org/A234728)
[A234738](https://oeis.org/A234738)
[A234823](https://oeis.org/A234823)
[A234867](https://oeis.org/A234867)
[A235017](https://oeis.org/A235017)
[A235026](https://oeis.org/A235026)
[A235087](https://oeis.org/A235087)
[A235098](https://oeis.org/A235098)
[A235107](https://oeis.org/A235107)
[A235175](https://oeis.org/A235175)
[A235186](https://oeis.org/A235186)
[A235198](https://oeis.org/A235198)
[A235212](https://oeis.org/A235212)
[A235239](https://oeis.org/A235239)
[A235248](https://oeis.org/A235248)
[A235258](https://oeis.org/A235258)
[A235280](https://oeis.org/A235280)
[A235289](https://oeis.org/A235289)
[A235301](https://oeis.org/A235301)
[A235310](https://oeis.org/A235310)
[A235319](https://oeis.org/A235319)
[A235884](https://oeis.org/A235884)
[A235893](https://oeis.org/A235893)
[A235954](https://oeis.org/A235954)
[A237015](https://oeis.org/A237015)
[A237637](https://oeis.org/A237637)
[A239287](https://oeis.org/A239287)
[A244027](https://oeis.org/A244027)
[A250742](https://oeis.org/A250742)
[A251128](https://oeis.org/A251128)
[A251149](https://oeis.org/A251149)
[A251236](https://oeis.org/A251236)
[A252254](https://oeis.org/A252254)
[A253044](https://oeis.org/A253044)
[A253468](https://oeis.org/A253468)
[A255228](https://oeis.org/A255228)
[A257361](https://oeis.org/A257361)
[A257447](https://oeis.org/A257447)
[A258316](https://oeis.org/A258316)
[A258612](https://oeis.org/A258612)
[A258894](https://oeis.org/A258894)
[A258921](https://oeis.org/A258921)
[A258957](https://oeis.org/A258957)
[A259222](https://oeis.org/A259222)
[A259704](https://oeis.org/A259704)
[A259770](https://oeis.org/A259770)
[A267089](https://oeis.org/A267089)
[A271709](https://oeis.org/A271709)
[A271710](https://oeis.org/A271710)
[A283845](https://oeis.org/A283845)
[A284128](https://oeis.org/A284128)
[A284131](https://oeis.org/A284131)
[A298594](https://oeis.org/A298594)
[A298597](https://oeis.org/A298597)
[A302339](https://oeis.org/A302339)
[A302346](https://oeis.org/A302346)
[A317773](https://oeis.org/A317773)
[A318354](https://oeis.org/A318354)
[A321126](https://oeis.org/A321126)
[A323621](https://oeis.org/A323621)
[A331886](https://oeis.org/A331886)
[A338032](https://oeis.org/A338032)
[A338796](https://oeis.org/A338796)
[A346500](https://oeis.org/A346500)
[A346517](https://oeis.org/A346517)
[A346538](https://oeis.org/A346538)
[A347563](https://oeis.org/A347563)
[A349039](https://oeis.org/A349039)
[A349203](https://oeis.org/A349203)
[A350770](https://oeis.org/A350770)
[A364480](https://oeis.org/A364480)
[A367108](https://oeis.org/A367108)

Comment: Would be nice to find the subset of the list above of those entries that describe a list of polynomials $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n,k} x^k$ for which  $a_{n,0} = a_{n,n}  \neq 0$ for $n$ say greater than $4$ . Another possibility is for OEIS entries for which $a_{n,0} =0$ and $a_{n,1} = a_{n,n}  \neq 0$ and the U property holds for the non-zero coefficients.   (Give a guy an inch and he'll take a mile.)